# XSLT Transformation to add multiple not existing child elements

Tags: xml, xslt

I've got a xml document, looking like this:

```
<p>
  <c1 />
  <c2 />
</p>
```

The child elements c1 and c2 are optional, but for a processing step I need them to be existent. So I am trying to create a xslt stylesheet to add them as empty elements (the order of the children does not matter).

Here is my stylesheet:

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p[not(c1)]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        <c1 />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p[not(c2)]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        <c2 />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

This works fine, as long as only one of the child elements is missing. But if both are missing, only c1 is created. How do I prevent that and force the creation of both c1 and c2 (and in reality, of about 10 children)?

Thanks.
Jost

Comment: Good question, +1. You might be interested in a generic solution that doesn't use any explicit XSLT conditional instructions and any `xsl:element` (which means that it is more readable, understandable and maintainable). Also, if you can use XSLT 2.0, please let me know and I will add an XSLT 2.0 solution, which is both simpler and shorter than the XSLT 1.0 solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
<xsl:template match="p"> 
  <xsl:copy> 
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/> 
    <xsl:if test="not(c1)">
      <c1 /> 
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="not(c2)">
      <c2 /> 
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:copy> 
</xsl:template>
```

If you have a longer list of possible child nodes you can put them in a variable and use a `for-each` instead than individual `if`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 
  exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:variable name="childrenFragment">
    <c1/>
    <c2/>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:template match="p">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      <xsl:variable name="this" select="."/>
      <xsl:for-each select="msxsl:node-set($childrenFragment)/*">
        <xsl:variable name="localName" select="local-name()"/>
        <xsl:if test="not($this/*[local-name()=$localName])">
          <xsl:element name="{$localName}"/>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

just add all the elements you need in the `childrenFragment` variable.

(the `msxsl:node-set` stuff is Microsoft-specific, if you are using another XSLT processor you'll need something slightly different)

Comment: Thanks :-) The first solution will suffice in my case, but i'll keep the second one in mind.

Answer (score 4):

Don't much like the `xsl:if` approach. Here's something that could be better, as long as you don't mind the ordering of the nodes changing:

```
<!--generic copy rule-->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates" select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!--copy rules specific to p-->
<xsl:template match="p">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="not(self::c1|self::c2)"/>
        <c1><xsl:apply-templates select="c1/*"/></c1>
        <c2><xsl:apply-templates select="c2/*"/></c2>
    </xsl:copy>
<xsl:template>
```

The basic idea is to explicitly generate the c1 and c2 nodes with their content if they are present or nothing if not.

Comment: +1 for the simple approach, but for this to work as expected, I had to change the last three selects to `select="*[not(self::c1|self::c2)]"`, `select="c1/*"` and `select="c2/*"` respectively, not sure if this is correct, or the best approach, as I am new to non-trivial XSLT, tested with libxml's xsltproc and java's standard TransformerFactory

Answer (score 2):

**Here is a generic XSLT 1.0 solution (can be used witn N to-be-added elements) that doesn't use any explicit XSLT conditional instructions or any `xsl:element` instruction**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common" exclude-result-prefixes="ext">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vrtfNodesToAdd">
  <c1/><c2/>
</xsl:variable>

 <xsl:variable name="vNodesToAdd" select=
  "ext:node-set($vrtfNodesToAdd)/*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="p">
   <xsl:variable name="vCurrentP" select="."/>

   <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>

    <xsl:for-each select="$vNodesToAdd">
       <xsl:copy-of select=
       "self::node()[not($vCurrentP/*[name() = name(current())])]"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document:**

```
<t>
 <p>
 </p>
 <p>
  <c1/>
 </p>
 <p>
  <c2/>
 </p>
 <p>
  <c1/><c2/>
 </p>
</t>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<t>
  <p>
    <c1 />
    <c2 />
  </p>
  <p>
    <c1 />
    <c2 />
  </p>
  <p>
    <c2 />
    <c1 />
  </p>
  <p>
    <c1 />
    <c2 />
  </p>
</t>
```